# What are valid values for the MediaType Property on a HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, html, httpwebrequest, webrequest

What are valid values for the MediaType Property on a HttpWebRequest?

I want to do something like this:

```
Dim url As String = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri
Dim req As System.Net.HttpWebRequest = DirectCast(System.Net.WebRequest.Create(New Uri(url)), System.Net.HttpWebRequest)
' Add the current authentication cookie to the request 
Dim cookie As HttpCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName)
Dim authenticationCookie As New System.Net.Cookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, cookie.Value, cookie.Path, HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Authority)

req.CookieContainer = New System.Net.CookieContainer()
req.CookieContainer.Add(authenticationCookie)
req.MediaType = "PRINT"

Dim res As System.Net.WebResponse = req.GetResponse()
'Read data 
Dim ResponseStream As Stream = res.GetResponseStream()
'Write content into the MemoryStream
Dim resReader As New BinaryReader(ResponseStream)
Dim docStream As New MemoryStream(resReader.ReadBytes(CInt(res.ContentLength)))
```

Thanks.

Comment: At least separate it to two questions, so it won't be too localized and not usable by others.

Comment: My only question is "What are valid values for the MediaType Property on a HttpWebRequest?" The rest is how I plain on using it. Sorry if that is not clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this wikipedia page should give you a fairly comprehensive list of media types:
[Media Types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_media_type)

Comment: IANA official list (more uptodate than WIKI link by @andy-rose), is here:  http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml